# Creating a customised plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I wanted a customized plot whose X-axis is the experiment number and there is a box plotted for every experiment. The height of the box is determined by two values (ymin and ymax) and the width of the box is same for all experiments.

I have tried to make such a plot using 4 geom_segment commands as follows

```
geom_segment(aes(y = open, yend = open, x = Exp - width / 4, xend = Exp + width / 4 )) +
geom_segment(aes(y = close, yend = close, x = Exp - width / 4, xend = Exp + width / 4 )) +
geom_segment(aes(y = pmin(open,close), yend = pmax(open,close), x = Exp - width / 4, xend = Exp - width / 4 )) +
geom_segment(aes(y = pmin(open,close), yend = pmax(open,close), x = Exp + width / 4, xend = Exp + width / 4 ))
```

where Exp=experiment number and width=1

Please find attached the plot. However I think There should be a better method than this. 
[image: Customised Plot]

Comment: Maybe `geom_rect` to draw whole rectangles instead of individual segments...?

Comment: Hey I did not know about geom_rect(). Thank you very much. It was very easy

Comment: Someone post it as an answer and mark it correct then.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. it easy to do with

```
geom_rect
```

[geom_rect function doc](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_rect.html)